# Bad request error from Google Analytics API

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, ssis-2012

//Please help to make this code workable

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Globalization;

    namespace GoogleAnalyticsSupport
    {
    public class ReportRequestorWithSorting
    {
    #region Fields

//I am getting bad request error

        private static readonly string requestUrlFormat = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data?ids={1}&metrics={2}&sort={3}&start-date={4}&end-date={5}&start-index={6}&max-results={7}";
    private static readonly string authUrlFormat = "accountType=GOOGLE&Email={0}&Passwd={1}&source=reimers.dk-analyticsreader-0.1&service=analytics";
    private static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    private string _token =  null;  
    private string _username = null;
    private string _password = null;


    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ReportRequestorWithSorting() { }

    public ReportRequestorWithSorting(string email, string password)
    {
    _username = email;
    _password = password;

    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Email
    {
    get { return _username; }

    set
    {
    if (!string.Equals(_username, value))
    {
    _username = value;
    _token = null;
    }
    }
    }

    public string Password
    {
    get { return _password; }
    set
    {
    if (!string.Equals(_password, value))
    {
    _password = value;
    _token = null;
    }
    }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

 \\struggling to replace the new authentication method\\

    private string GetToken(string username, string password)
    {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_password))
    {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Username, Password", "Username and/or password not set");
    }

    string authBody = string.Format(authUrlFormat, username, password);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.UserAgent = "Example.dk req";

    Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
    sw.Write(authBody);
    sw.Close();
    sw.Dispose();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string token = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] tokens = token.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string item in tokens)
    {
    if (item.StartsWith("Auth="))
    {
    return item.Replace("Auth=", "");
    }
    }

    return string.Empty;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AnalyticsAccountInfo> GetAccounts()
    {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_token))
    {
    _token = GetToken(_username, _password);
    }

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts");
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" + _token);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string responseXml = sr.ReadToEnd();

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);
    XNamespace dxpSpace = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dxp");
    XNamespace defaultSpace = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    var entries = from en in doc.Root.Descendants(defaultSpace + "entry")
    select new AnalyticsAccountInfo
    {
    AccountID = en.Elements(dxpSpace + "property").Where(xe => xe.Attribute("name").Value == "ga:accountId").First().Attribute("value").Value,
    AccountName = en.Elements(dxpSpace + "property").Where(xe => xe.Attribute("name").Value == "ga:accountName").First().Attribute("value").Value,
    ID = en.Element(defaultSpace + "id").Value,
    Title = en.Element(defaultSpace + "title").Value,
    ProfileID = en.Elements(dxpSpace + "property").Where(xe => xe.Attribute("name").Value == "ga:profileId").First().Attribute("value").Value,
    WebPropertyID = en.Elements(dxpSpace + "property").Where(xe => xe.Attribute("name").Value == "ga:webPropertyId").First().Attribute("value").Value
    };

    return entries;
    }

    private XDocument getReport(AnalyticsAccountInfo account, IEnumerable<Dimension> dimensions, IEnumerable<Metric> metrics
    , IEnumerable<Sort> sorts, DateTime from, DateTime to, int startindex = 1, int maxresults = 250)
    {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_token))
    {
    _token = GetToken(_username, _password);
    }

    StringBuilder dims = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Dimension item in dimensions)
    {
    dims.Append("ga:" + item.ToString() + ",");
    }

    StringBuilder mets = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Metric item in metrics)
    {
    mets.Append("ga:" + item.ToString() + ",");
    }
    StringBuilder srt = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Sort item in sorts)
    {
    srt.Append("-" + "ga:" + item.ToString() + ",");
    }
    string requestUrl = string.Format(requestUrlFormat, "ga:" + account.ProfileID, dims.ToString().Trim(",".ToCharArray()), mets.ToString().Trim(",".ToCharArray())
    , srt.ToString().Trim(",".ToCharArray()), from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), startindex, maxresults);

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" + _token);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string responseXml = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8, true).ReadToEnd();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);

    return doc;
    }


    public IEnumerable<GenericEntry> ReportRequestWF(AnalyticsAccountInfo account, IEnumerable<Dimension> dimensions, IEnumerable<Metric> metrics
    , IEnumerable<Sort> sorts, DateTime from, DateTime to, int startindex = 1, int maxresults = 250)
    {
    XDocument doc = getReport(account, dimensions, metrics
    , sorts, from, to, startindex, maxresults);
    XNamespace dxpSpace = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dxp");
    XNamespace defaultSpace = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    var gr = from r in doc.Root.Descendants(defaultSpace + "entry")
    select new GenericEntry
    {
    Dimensions = new List<KeyValuePair<Dimension, string>>(
    from rd in r.Elements(dxpSpace + "dimension")
    select new KeyValuePair<Dimension, string>(
    (Dimension)Enum.Parse(
    typeof(Dimension),
    rd.Attribute("name").Value.Replace("ga:", ""),
    true),
    rd.Attribute("value").Value)),
    Metrics = new List<KeyValuePair<Metric, string>>(
    from rm in r.Elements(dxpSpace + "metric")
    select new KeyValuePair<Metric, string>(
    (Metric)Enum.Parse(typeof(Metric), rm.Attribute("name").Value.Replace("ga:", ""), true),
    rm.Attribute("value").Value)),

    Sorts = new List<KeyValuePair<Sort, string>>(
    from rs in r.Elements(dxpSpace + "sort")
    select new KeyValuePair<Sort, string>(
    (Sort)Enum.Parse(typeof(Sort), rs.Attribute("name").Value.Replace("ga:", ""), true),
    rs.Attribute("value").Value))

    };

    return gr;
    }
    #endregion
    }
    }
```

Just created generic, dimension and metrics class files and called them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code will not work.   You appear to be trying to authenticate with client login (login and password)  Google shut down client login April 2015 you can no longer use client login to access Google APIs.

You will need to move to using Oauth2 or a service account

Normaly I would recomend using the [.net client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/) but you appear to be trying to merge this into SSIS at this time the .net client library is not strong name signed so wont work with ssis.   You will have to manually recreate the Oauth2 flow.

**Useful Links**

- Tutorial: [Google 3 legged Oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)
- [Custom Google Analytics SSIS task and connection manager](http://www.daimto.com/targit-google-analytics-ssis/) (note I am a developer on this project)

Comment: Solved using service account method